# How to calculate the time remaining in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script:

**CODE JS:**

```
    var completeD = start.format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm");
    var dt = new Date(completeD);
    $("#time").val(normalize(dt.getHours()) + ":" + normalize(dt.getMinutes()));
    var star_H=$("#time").val();
    console.log("star_h",star_H);  //04:00--after execution

    var completeF = end.format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm");
    var dtf = new Date(completeF);
    $("#duration").val(normalize(dtf.getHours()) + ":" + normalize(dtf.getMinutes()));
    var end_H=$("#duration").val();
    console.log("end_H",end_H); //04:30--after execution
    var result=new Date(end_H - star_H);

    console.log(result);   // ERROR:INVALID DATA--here should be 00:30 min
```

I want to fall during the final, during initial duration of an event to find out ...

It sees all too clear in my intent code :)

You please tell me how to do this better and work?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
   function normalize(n) {
            if (n < 10) {
                n = "0" + n;
            }
            return n;
        }
```

Comment: what exactly are `start` and `end`, and where are these `format` and `normalize` functions coming from?

Comment: can you pls post the code in jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: We added normalize function ... and start is a parameter from fullcalendar

Comment: What version of fullcalendar?. If it's a version using `moment` can do this very simply with a moment date difference method

Comment: I do not know exactly what version it is, but there is no problem ...

Answer (score 0):

you're tring to subtract strings.

```
var completeD = start.format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm");
var dt = new Date(completeD); //<--- use this
$("#time").val(normalize(dt.getHours()) + ":" + normalize(dt.getMinutes()));
var star_H=$("#time").val();
console.log("star_h",star_H);  //04:00--after execution

var completeF = end.format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm");
var dtf = new Date(completeF); //<--- use this
$("#duration").val(normalize(dtf.getHours()) + ":" + normalize(dtf.getMinutes()));
var end_H=$("#duration").val();
console.log("end_H",end_H); //04:30--after execution

// try this:
var result=new Date(dtf - dt);
```

Comment: this is console result star_h 04:30
end_H 05:00
 Thu Jan 01 1970 02:30:00 GMT+0200 (EET)